# How to define array of closures in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, closures

I want to define like this:

```
public var reloadFRCsNeedToPerformWhenFail = [()->()]()
```

but I get an error

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this:

```
public var reloadFRCsNeedToPerformWhenFail : [()->()] = []
```

If you use a type alias to make `()->()` a type, you can do it your way:

```
public typealias VoidVoid = ()->()
public var reloadFRCsNeedToPerformWhenFail = [VoidVoid]()
```

Or, forego the `[]` shortcut notation and use the full generic:

```
public var reloadFRCsNeedToPerformWhenFail = Array<()->()>()
```

Comment: Added another workaround; the heart of the problem seems to be the `[...]` shortcut notation.