# Storing closures of different types in array in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

Lets say I want to have an array of functions (closures) that I will later want to dispatch. I want all the closures to take an Array of any type as a single parameter.

I tried:

```
var closureList: [(Array) -> Void]
```

This gives a compiler error: reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>

I don't want to store closure of a certain type of Array but any type of Array so I tried this:

```
protocol GeneralArray {

}

extension Array: GeneralArray {

}

var closureList: [(GeneralArray) -> Void]
```

This compiles but when I try to append a closure:

```
func intArrayFunc([Int]) -> Void {

}

closureList.append(intArrayFunc)
```

I get a compiler error: cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(([Int]) -> Void)'.

Is there a way in swift to store closures that take different types as parameters in an array?

Comment: generics. (GeneralArray) -> Void is expected, and you are passing (Int) -> Void. Try func intArrayFunc([GeneralArray]) -> Void. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829763/how-to-define-array-of-closures-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Using `GeneralArray` is in this case almost the same as using `[Any]` instead. Therefore a function of type `[Int] -> Void` is not convertible to such a type.

But in order to have a general way to handle any array a `GeneralArray` would probably have a property of type `[Any]`:

```
protocol GeneralArray {
    var anyArray: [Any] { get }
}

extension Array: GeneralArray {
    var anyArray: [Any] {
        return self.map{ $0 as Any }
    }
}

var closureList: [(GeneralArray) -> Void] = []

func intArrayFunc([Int]) -> Void {

}
```

So you have to wrap the function in a closure which is of type `(GeneralArray) -> Void` :

```
// wrapping the function in an appropriate closure
closureList.append({ array in intArrayFunc(array.anyArray.map{ $0 as! Int }) })

// with a helper function
closureList.append(functionConverter(intArrayFunc))
```

There are two possible helper functions which can "convert" the function:

```
func functionConverter<T>(f: [T] -> Void) -> GeneralArray -> Void {
    return { array in
        // "safe" conversion to an array of type [T]
        let arr: [T] = array.anyArray.flatMap{
            if let value = $0 as? T {
                return [value]
            }
            return []
        }
        f(arr)
    }
}

func unsafeFunctionConverter<T>(f: [T] -> Void) -> GeneralArray -> Void {
    return { array in
        f(array.anyArray.map{ $0 as! T })
    }
}
```